# MYSQL Table Grouping

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to group tables in mysql?

That is, say i'm using PHP My Admin, and all the tables are listed on the left, can I have them in some sort of folder structure or group?

I'm fairly sure this isn't possible.... and if it is, i'm going to guess that it's an application layer thing, ie something that a particular app will allow you to do.

So if that is the case, does anyone know the name of such an application with this feature?

Thanks

Comment: Is this just a cosmetic thing or do you want some type of data relationship between the tables - not sure I understand what you are attempting to do?

Comment: It's just a cosmetic thing, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, There isn't a way to do this.

Comment: I think OP ask for grouping for the purpose of visualization.

Shall we create separate database for each "group" and work with sub-databases and use some sort of script to sync table with main database?

Like crm_party (all user & org tables), crm roles, crm_contacts, etc. We can also duplicate same table across multiple sub-databases. Do you think it is worth the efforts?

Answer (score 1):

Navicat for MySQL allows you to do this - although I think it just changes the way Navicat displays the tables, not the underlying database at all.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin I think it's possible if you're giving some tables the same prefix (eg jason_users & jason_posts)

see http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/forums/forum/72909/topic/3777476